# How to save the .pkpass file in a server directory using php

Tags: php, jquery, download, passbook

I am using the php .pkpass library, the file is generated correctly, but it is downloaded directly in Windows Downloads, I would like it to be saved in a folder of my application for example /upload/

The class brings this structure

```
// Output pass
if($output == true) {
    $fileName = $this->getName() ? $this->getName() : $name;
    if(!strstr($fileName, '.')) {
        $fileName .= '.pkpass';
    }
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T'));
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
    @ob_end_flush();
    set_time_limit(0);
    echo $file;
    return true;
}
```

I'm trying something like that but it doesn't work out. helpe me please

```
<?php
$filename = 'upload/file.pkpass';

 # Download the File                        
$handle = fopen($filename, "w");
fwrite($handle, $ics_data);
fclose($handle);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename);
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));    
readfile($filename);    
exit();     
?>
```

Comment: This is not so much about how you are sending the bundle, more so about how your application is requesting it. How is your windows application requesting the pass?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answering, but I think it explains badly, I just wanted to save my file in a directory, I realized that I was forcing the download of the file at the time of executing my action, I solved it in the following way and just deleted the headers

```
if($output == true) {
    $fileName = $this->getName() ? $this->getName() : $name;
    if(!strstr($fileName, '.')) {
        $fileName .= '.pkpass';
    }
    $fileName = 'upload/pkpass/'.$fileName;                   
    $fp = fopen($fileName, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $file);
    fclose($fp); 
}
```

regards